# I have two set of input fields for two different forms. How can I use them dynamically for any form?

Tags: reactjs, forms, input, frontend

I am new to react. I am trying to build dynamic form component of a set of input fields using react which can be reused in any single form as a set of inputs. How can I access those input data dynamically?

For example, the form for the set of reusable inputs:

```
export default class dynamicForm extends Component {
handleSubmit = event => {
 // get dynamic input data. But how?
}

render() {
    return (
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
 <CustomInputs1/>
 <CustomInputs2/>
 <input type="submit" value="confirm"/>
</form>
)}
```

Input set no. 1 as custom input:

```
export default class CustomInputs1 extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {      
      input1: "",
      input2: ""
    };
    this.inputInput1Ref = React.createRef();
    this.inputInput2Ref = React.createRef();
}

handleInputChange = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { input1 } = this.state;
    const { input2 } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="input1" value={input1} onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
        <input type="text" name="input2" value={input2} onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Input set no. 2 as custom input:

```
export default class CustomInputs2 extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {      
      input3: "",
      input4: ""
    };
    this.inputInput3Ref = React.createRef();
    this.inputInput4Ref = React.createRef();
}

handleInputChange = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { input3 } = this.state;
    const { input4 } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="input3" value={input3} onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
        <input type="text" name="input4" value={input4} onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

There can be more reusable input groups like this.I just added two group as example.

Comment: A few things: You are not using the refs you are creating in the `CustomInputs`, so those lines can go. Also, you can destructure the state in one line, like so: ´const {input1, input2} = this.state´. Now for your problem: You can either create refs to the `CustomInputs` in your `dynamicForm` and simply access the state of your custom inputs when the form is submitted or pass a function as props to each `CustomInputs` which writes the input to the state of `dynamicForm`. First option is probably easier ;)

Comment: Thank you very much @Taxel . It works as tried the first option. That was really easy. Sorry for dumb question. It also clear me about the use of reference. You might write it as answer :) . Good day to you.

Answer (score 1):

A few things: You are not using the refs you are creating in the CustomInputs, so those lines can go. Also, you can destructure the state in one line, like so: `const {input1, input2} = this.state`.

Now for your problem: You can either create refs to the `CustomInputs` in your `dynamicForm` and simply access the state of your custom inputs when the form is submitted or pass a function as props to each `CustomInputs` which writes the input to the `state` of `dynamicForm`. First option is probably easier ;)